# i18n wants to load an unspecified translation

Tags: internationalization, aurelia, i18next

I'm currently working on an Aurelia project (web framework like Angular2).
I followed the guide on their [github account](https://github.com/aurelia/i18n#how-to-install-this-plugin) but encountered a problem.

First, the browser returned me this error: 
`GET http://localhost:9000/src/locale/nl/translation.json?_=1450946571510 404 (Not Found)`

Secondly, I'm using two languages in my application: Dutch (nl-BE) and French (fr-BE).

Here is how my folder structure looks like:

```
src (inside root)
.. locale 
..... fr-BE 
........ translation.json 
..... nl-BE
........ translation.json
```

Here is what my full main.js file looks like:

```
import 'bootstrap';
import {I18N} from 'aurelia-i18n';

export function configure(aurelia) {

    aurelia.use
        .standardConfiguration()
        .developmentLogging()
        .globalResources('converters/dateFormat')
        .plugin('components/index')
        .plugin('plugins/index')
        .plugin('aurelia-i18n', (instance) => {
            instance.setup({
                resGetPath: 'src/locale/__lng__/__ns__.json',
                lng: 'nl-BE',
                attributes: ['t', 'i18n'],
                getAsync: true,
                sendMissing: false,
                fallbackLng: 'fr-BE',
                debug: false
            });
        });
    aurelia.start().then(a => a.setRoot());
}
```

I'm trying to setup a hello world where I have my view and viewmodel set like this:

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {I18N} from 'aurelia-i18n';

@inject(I18N)
export class EntryDetails {
    constructor(i18n){
        this.i18n = i18n;
        this.i18n.setLocale('nl-BE').then(() => console.log('test'));
    }
}
```

And my view:

```
<template>
    <span t="hello"></span> <span t="world"></span>
</template>
```

**The problem is not that it's not working. The problem is that I'm getting an error that states my folder `nl` is missing in my `locale` folder. But I never specified that anywhere..**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is how i18next resolves translation files.

```
The lookup order for keys is always:

nl-BE language + country 
nl language only
fallback thats defined in options.fallbackLng (en) (string or array of fallback language)

loaded resources:

locale/en/translation.json
locale/nl/translation.json
locale/nl-BE/translation.json
```

http://i18next.com/translate/#resolve

So you need to have nl/translation.json, even if it is not specified in config. It can be just empty but valid json file with content `{}`

Comment: I thought of this, but yet seems so "stupid" as a solution, or is that just me? But it would surely solve the problem yeah.

Comment: if you don't have other nl-... and fr-... locale it would be simplier to have just nl and fr locale as main and not to use country specific locales like nl-BE or fr-BE

Comment: You got a valid point there. I'd edit your message and it in there ;)